# How to add text next to icon in title bar ( wpf )

Tags: wpf, text, icons, titlebar

How to add text next to icon in title bar without customizing the whole window (creating my own exit and minimize button etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not referring to the `Title` property of the `Window` class, then I'm afraid you will need to re-template.